Chinese seal on bottom of old chess pieces
I have an old chinese chess set. Each piece has a seal on the bottom. This is one seal. Does anyone know what it means?


read it as “大清乾隆”, the characters were, . . . quite derived from standard

If it is really 乾隆, that's mean it was made on year 1736~1796.

wow. so the piece was made sometime between 1736 and 1795?

It is 大清乾隆 (the Qing Dynasty, Qianlong emperor's reign)
大清 = the Qing Dynasty
乾隆 = Qianlong (Emperor Qianlong's reign was 1736 - 1795)
The seal just told you when the item was made
